# raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" % ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-datetime

I have a file with this line(datetime string) and I need to convert this into datetime object

2021-04-08 21:16:03.553221

but python returns error, although everything is fine, I guess.
This is my code

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    first_line_in_file = f.readline()
first_line = datetime.datetime.strptime(first_line_in_file, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: which Python version are you using? For Python 3.7+, `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(first_line_in_file)` should do fine.

Comment: Your `first_line_in_file` variable has a trailing linebreak character `\n`.

Comment: @MrFuppes, `datetime.fromisoformat(...)` also complains when the string ends with `\n'`.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel right, something like a `first_line_in_file.strip()` should help then. I think you got the point here, you could add it as an answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks!:) Ya'll helped me!